# jquery file-upload-plugin - drag and drop not working in firefox 3.6

Tags: jquery, html, file-upload

For reasons I won't go in to I need to support firefox 3.6 with drag and drop file upload functionality.  Unfortunately the jquery-file-upload doesn't seem to support 3.6, the documentation says it does but I can't get drag n drop to work even the demo page doesn't work with ff3.6 http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/

Anyone else managed to get this going?  I know this browser supports the HTML5 fileupload API and I've managed to get dnd working with another library but I only want to switch if i have to.

Comment: Good idea, I've created an issue...